# how can i return and increment in the same for-loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, return, increment

I've encountered the problem where if I increment the for-loop my program crashes after the for-loop has been executed, but if I don't increment the for-loop and use a return statement to return `projectedSales` my program continues to run.

However, if I don't increase then `projectedSales` just outputs the last number for `projectedSales1` without adding it to `projectedSales`.

So my question here is, how can i increment the for-loop so that `projectedSales  = projectedSales + projectedSales1` continues to collect data and returns `projectedSales` at the end?

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double projectedRevenue2025 = 0;
    double projectedSales1 = 0;
    double projectedSales = 0;
    double baseSales;
    double growthRate;
    double numberOfYears;
    int [] productPrice = {1825, 670, 880, 1910, 485};

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");

    for (double i = 0; i <= 4;) {
        System.out.println("What is the base sale?");
        baseSales = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the growth rate?");
        growthRate = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("What is the expected number of years?");
        numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();

        //calculates the projected sales of the upcoming years
        projectedSales1 = baseSales * (Math.pow((1 + (growthRate / 100)), numberOfYears));

        System.out.println("The projected sale is: " + df.format(projectedSales1));
        //this should store data from projectedSales1 into projectedSales and add it to the previous data
        projectedSales = projectedSales + projectedSales1;

        projectedRevenue2025 = (projectedSales1 * productPrice[(int) i]) + projectedRevenue2025;
        System.out.println("The total projected revenue is: $" + df.format(projectedRevenue2025)); //prints total projected revenue
        return projectedSales;
    } //close for-loop      

    input.close();

    return projectedSales;
} //closes projSales
```

PS. the return statement after `input.close()` is to return `projectedSales` to the main method

EDIT: I was supposed to hard code this program. My issue was with the input statements in the beginning of the loop. Thank you all, I really appreciate y'all taking the time to help.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when program crashes? By the way, you should not use `double` variable as for-loop counter in that case,  I also recommend you to avoid naming variables like `var1, var2, var 2025...`

Comment: I think this code for-loop will just only run for only 1 time and then return to the main method

Comment: @Steyrix _java.util.NoSuchElementException_ is the error message i get.

Comment: @yshaikh20x have you tried the solution I proposed in my answer? Does it work?

Comment: @Steyrix yes I tried that but without a return statement it gives me the error message: _Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source) at project4.project4.projSales(project4.java:61) at project4.project4.main(project4.java:36)_  Where line 61 is `baseSales=input.nextDouble();` and line 36 is `productSales2025=projSales();` which is located in the main method

Comment: @yshaikh20x I am not really familiar with the Scanner, but it seems like it tries to retrieve double values from empty input stream (I assume scanner does not meet any double values after the first iteration of for-loop). How many values do you type in console when program starts? Try to type in 15 values: (baseSales, growthRate, numerOfYears) x 5

Comment: @Steyrix in my understanding Scanner is used to retrieve a user inputted answer. When the program reaches the loop I input a total of 15 numbers ( baseSales, growthRate, and numberOfYears each 5 times) like you are suggesting but that isnt my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use for-loop like this in your case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Do your input and previous calculations
    projectedRevenue2025 = (projectedSales1 * productPrice[i]) + projectedRevenue2025;
}
```

*I also recommend you to avoid naming variables like `var, var1, var2, var2025`*

Answer (score 0):

Try adding i++ code is like this

```
for (double i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
//code goes here
}
```

Comment: When i do this i get the error message _java.util.NoSuchElementException_. But if i exclude the i++ anywhere in the for-loop and use a return statement then my program continues with the code without incrementing `i`.

Comment: _Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source) at project4.project4.projSales(project4.java:61) at project4.project4.main(project4.java:36)_ Where line 61 is `baseSales=input.nextDouble();` and line 36 is `productSales2025=projSales();` which is located in the main method

Answer (score 0):

if you take out the return statement in the loop and increment the for loop then it should collect data every time and then at the end return the sum of all of the data

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double projectedRevenue2025 = 0;
double projectedSales1 = 0;
double projectedSales = 0;
double baseSales;
double growthRate;
double numberOfYears;
int [] productPrice = {1825, 670, 880, 1910, 485};

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");

for (double i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("What is the base sale?");
    baseSales = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the growth rate?");
    growthRate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the expected number of years?");
    numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();

    //calculates the projected sales of the upcoming years
    projectedSales1 = baseSales * (Math.pow((1 + (growthRate / 100)), numberOfYears));

    System.out.println("The projected sale is: " + df.format(projectedSales1));
    //this should store data from projectedSales1 into projectedSales and add it to the previous data
    projectedSales = projectedSales + projectedSales1;

    projectedRevenue2025 = (projectedSales1 * productPrice[(int) i]) + projectedRevenue2025;
    System.out.println("The total projected revenue is: $" + df.format(projectedRevenue2025)); //prints total projected revenue
} //close for-loop      

input.close();

return projectedSales;
} //closes projSales
```

Comment: i've tired this. I always get the error message _java.util.NoSuchElementException_.

Comment: @yshaikh20x could you possibly paste the full error message? running the code by itself doesn't provide any errors

Comment: This isnt the entire code, its just the part that I'm having trouble with. 
 _Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at project4.project4.projSales(project4.java:61)
 at project4.project4.main(project4.java:36)_                                                              This is the entire error message. Line 61 is `baseSales=input.nextDouble();` and line 36 is `productSales2025=projSales();` which is located in the main method.